# rsyslogd: how can you use $ModLoad imfile more than once?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, syslog

I am testing out Loggly.com, which uses rsyslogd to collect log entries. Loggly provides scripts that generate config files. Each config file starts with `$ModLoad imfile`, however this seems to only work for the first config, subsequent configs will not be included and generate the error:

```
$ rsyslogd -N1
rsyslogd: version 8.16.0, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: module 'imfile' already in this config, cannot be added  [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2221 ]
```

Some other conf systems will allow you to declare something along the lines of

`if not imfile $ModLoad imfile`

Is there something similar for rsyslogd? Is this a very obvious oversight on the part of Loggly, or (more likely) is there something I am missing?

FWIW here is an example of the folder layout for rsyslogd:

```
crw@beta:/etc/rsyslog.d$ ls
20-ufw.conf  21-cloudinit.conf  21-filemonitoring-web-err.conf  21-nginx.conf  22-loggly.conf  50-default.conf
```

The 21-* files are auto-generated by Loggly scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `loggly.com` in particular, but I am familiar with rsyslog. All of the conf files in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` are being incorporated by the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file where it says:

`$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`

When rsyslog reads its configuration it does not read the configuration files as if they were separate. It's all concatenated into a single stream of input. If those files were generated by loggly and each had that same `$ModLoad` line, I believe that to be an oversight on their part. They may have not noticed because while it does generate those error logs it doesn't actually prevent rsyslog from starting or running.

Lastly, I don't know of an rsyslog if-statement that works with the `$ModLoad` variable. I'd recommend removing those extra `$ModLoad` statements. Alternatively, you could choose to ignore those errors since they are benign.

Comment: One symptom of this error appears to be that any conf file that throws this error is not included in the conf "stream." Is there a way to test this locally? All I can see is that data is not making it into Loggly. I mention this specifically as you seem to be saying this error should be ignored, whereas it seems to invalidate the entire conf file.

Comment: I am also facing the same issues. I have two different custom configuration files to push squid logs to my tcp end points but only one of them is working. Any solution ?

Comment: Would it make sense to create a new .conf file and only add `$ModLoad imfile` to that file and remove it from other .conf files?